What would cause packet loss from a gateway to an ISP?
I am trying to troubleshoot constant drops in internet connection. My home network is just a TP-Link router connected to an ISP-provided Arris modem.
I first tried running smokeping to 8.8.8.8 see how often the connection would drop, which shows that my internet connection drops every 15-30 minutes for about 30-90 seconds at a time. The graph can be seen here.

Then, I ran mtr to 8.8.8.8 and waited for the internet to drop again. As you can see here, when the internet drops the 100% packet loss begins as soon as the packet leaves the gateway to 96.120.x.x (the Comcast network).

Modem logs show "RCS Partial Service" immediately followed by "SYNC Timing Synchronization failure" each time that the internet connection drops. There are 32 downstream channels with a frequency from 393 MHz to 585 MHz, power from -7.5 dBmV to -11.0 dBmV, and each one has an SNR of 38±1 dB.
I assume this means that my equipment is fine since the link between my laptop and the gateway is okay. So, if this means that there is an issue with the link between my equipment and the nearest Comcast host, then what is the most that can I do as a customer to diagnose further?
The full DOCSIS metrics are here:
Channel Lock Status Modulation  Channel ID  Frequency   Power   SNR Corrected   Uncorrectables
1   Locked  256QAM  13  465.00 MHz  -10.00 dBmV 38.61 dB    259718  5630220
2   Locked  256QAM  1   393.00 MHz  -7.50 dBmV  38.98 dB    359 117
3   Locked  256QAM  2   399.00 MHz  -7.90 dBmV  38.98 dB    331 133
4   Locked  256QAM  3   405.00 MHz  -7.90 dBmV  38.98 dB    291 136
5   Locked  256QAM  4   411.00 MHz  -8.10 dBmV  38.98 dB    424 135
6   Locked  256QAM  5   417.00 MHz  -8.40 dBmV  38.98 dB    455 115
7   Locked  256QAM  6   423.00 MHz  -8.60 dBmV  38.61 dB    7682    21001
8   Locked  256QAM  7   429.00 MHz  -8.70 dBmV  38.98 dB    26211   112939
9   Locked  256QAM  8   435.00 MHz  -9.10 dBmV  38.98 dB    532964  3170651
10  Locked  256QAM  9   441.00 MHz  -9.20 dBmV  38.61 dB    150830  826442
11  Locked  256QAM  10  447.00 MHz  -9.40 dBmV  38.61 dB    71618   370292
12  Locked  256QAM  11  453.00 MHz  -9.70 dBmV  38.61 dB    416 104
13  Locked  256QAM  12  459.00 MHz  -9.50 dBmV  37.64 dB    15652   412541
14  Locked  256QAM  14  471.00 MHz  -10.50 dBmV 37.36 dB    858 155
15  Locked  256QAM  15  477.00 MHz  -10.40 dBmV 37.36 dB    1059    1078
16  Locked  256QAM  16  483.00 MHz  -10.60 dBmV 37.36 dB    572 114
17  Locked  256QAM  17  489.00 MHz  -11.00 dBmV 37.36 dB    425 78
18  Locked  256QAM  18  495.00 MHz  -10.90 dBmV 37.64 dB    422 56
19  Locked  256QAM  19  507.00 MHz  -10.60 dBmV 37.36 dB    15826   5133
20  Locked  256QAM  20  513.00 MHz  -9.80 dBmV  37.64 dB    152 30
21  Locked  256QAM  21  519.00 MHz  -9.10 dBmV  37.64 dB    122 32
22  Locked  256QAM  22  525.00 MHz  -9.00 dBmV  37.64 dB    68  30
23  Locked  256QAM  23  531.00 MHz  -8.50 dBmV  37.64 dB    74  25
24  Locked  256QAM  24  537.00 MHz  -7.80 dBmV  38.61 dB    64  27
25  Locked  256QAM  26  543.00 MHz  -7.70 dBmV  38.60 dB    49  27
26  Locked  256QAM  27  549.00 MHz  -7.40 dBmV  38.20 dB    30  25
27  Locked  256QAM  28  555.00 MHz  -6.90 dBmV  38.90 dB    35  5
28  Locked  256QAM  29  561.00 MHz  -6.80 dBmV  38.90 dB    51  0
29  Locked  256QAM  30  567.00 MHz  -6.60 dBmV  38.60 dB    53  0
30  Locked  256QAM  31  573.00 MHz  -6.10 dBmV  38.60 dB    41  0
31  Locked  256QAM  32  579.00 MHz  -6.40 dBmV  38.60 dB    34  0
32  Locked  256QAM  33  585.00 MHz  -6.30 dBmV  38.60 dB    30  0


Did you look at the DOCSIS interface status, diags, and logs in the admin web page of your DOCSIS modem/gateway?

@Spiff Modem logs show "RCS Partial Service" immediately followed by "SYNC Timing Synchronization failure" each time that the internet connection drops. There are 32 downstream channels with a frequency from 393 MHz to 585 MHz, power from -7.5 dBmV to -11.0 dBmV, and each one has an SNR of 38±1 dB. This looks normal to me-- could these numbers spontaneously change during a connection drop?

@Addy The ideal signal range is 0dBmV +/- 7. So they need to increase your signal by about 9dB. But that SNR seems pretty good so maybe this is just a red herring. How did the error counters look?
